# When calling an object method on an integer literal (such as ToString), is the CLR boxing the literal first?

Tags: .net, literals, boxing

I wonder if boxing is taking place in order for ToString() to be called on the integer literal (5):

```
5.ToString();
```

Oh, and if not, what is taking place in order for the CLR to be able to call the ToString() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't require boxing - because `int` overrides `ToString`. The compiler can determine exactly which method will be called, so it doesn't need to go through virtual dispatch. It doesn't even use callvirt - that call will correspond to IL of

```
call instance string [mscorlib]System.Int32::ToString()
```

If you *don't* override `ToString()` (etc) in a struct, then calls to the virtual method will require boxing.

Comment: @Richard: It's not an object - but you'll effectively get a local variable which is assigned a value using "ldc.i4.5; stloc.1". Simplest way to check is to run ildasm or Reflector :)

Comment: Thanks Jon! :-) And to answer my own question in my comment above (about it being a double), _ECMA-334: 9.4.4.2 Integer Literals_ says "If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong. If the literal has no suffix, it has the first of these types in which its value can be represented: int, uint, long, ulong." So it would be an int in my example. If I had used 5.2.ToString() in my example, it would have created a ulong type local variable. Found here - http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_9.4.4.2_Integer_literals

Comment: @Richard by suffix what they mean is 5d.ToString() for example where "d" is the suffix for double.

Comment: @Shiv: 5.2.ToString() would have used double rather than ulong, because it's not an integer literal at that point.

Comment: @Jon, yes. Did I say otherwise? I was merely trying to clarify "suffix" in the documentation, hence his confusion about 5.2 being considered a ulong.

Comment: @Shiv: Sorry, that was meant to be to Richard, not you. Doh!

Comment: @Jon I was beginning to wonder, I mean It's 5:30 am here, while you've been up for a while....:)

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, I guess I was up a little too late too. Obviously 5.2 is not an int!  :-)